Regular expressions Haproxy
Hi I want to write a regular expression to search SQL Injection.
For example
‘123) ORDER BY 1-- KhUB’)])
‘123) ORDER BY 1435-- SQlQ’)])
‘123) ORDER BY 1-- wIYj’)])
‘123) ORDER BY 3116-- AdZB’)])
‘123)) ORDER BY 1-- NCMu’)])


I did
    acl sql_injection path_reg -i .*ORDER\s+BY\s*(-?\d+)(--|\#)?.*


but it doesn’t work for me, I don’t understand why in regextester I checked everything and it finds everything,
PCRE2 library supports JIT : yes
Do I understand correctly that PCRE2 language is for regulars?
Please help me
I tried
ORDER\s+BY, but that doesn't work either.
I'm waiting for the injection to block.

I don't have a solution, but a comment that I've seen products come and go that attempted to use expression-based rules to detect SQL injection. They all failed, because such solutions have too many edge cases, and the attackers can work around them. SQL injection firewalls now use allowlisting i.e. enumerating all the SQL queries known to be legitimate in a given application, and disallowing all other SQL.

As Bill says in the comments, deny lists are relatively trivial for hackers to bypass.  Allowlists (positive validation) are harder to implement, but much more secure.  Even if you can get this working, it's the wrong thing.
If you are looking for firewall regex rules for security don't reinvent the wheel.  OWASP has a set of well tested ModSecurity rules which you should look at - I believe HAProxy can run ModSecurity rules.  However, the SQL*Injection ones are not that effective (see above).
